# How to create a new file and save to root directory when updating a post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function that runs when I save a post in wordpress. I need it to create a new file when I save and put it in the root directory.
I've tried the below code but it isn't saving a file anywhere that I can see.

```
  function create_custom_xml_sitemap($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before)
  {

      $xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <urlset 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" 
            xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
                <url>
                    <loc>http://www.codexworld.com</loc>
                    <lastmod>2016-07-04T07:46:18+00:00</lastmod>
                    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
                    <priority>1.00</priority>
                </url>
            </urlset>';


      $xml = new DOMDocument;
      $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
      $xml->loadXML($xmlString);

      $xml->save('xml/sitemap2.xml');
    
  }
add_action('post_updated', 'create_custom_xml_sitemap', 10, 3);
```